# okhttp does not allow for setting of content-type

Tags: java, http, okhttp

I have attempted to set the content type header of my request however okhttp automatically adds content-type to the end of the header list and sets it as application/json; charset=UTF-8 although I have simply set it to application/json.

Has anybody else experienced this? If so, I can make a pull request.

I have found out okhttp does not send this header properly via fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your request body, convert the JSON string to bytes first using whichever character encoding you prefer. If you use a byte[] to create a request body OkHttp won't add a charset parameter to the content type.

Comment: Hello, this did not work for me. This is how I am setting it.

//param is a byte[] array
`RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(param, JSON);
request.post(body);`

Comment: Removing the JSON parameter in the RequestBody.create function fixed the issue! Thanks!